# Roku: roUrlTransfer with dynamic url return empty

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am building a channel that call two xml files, the first one contain the links for the contents that will be shown in every row, the first call it work fine because i am using a static url

```
url = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
url.SetUrl("http://theRowsContents.xml")
rsp = url.GetToString()

responseXML = ParseXML(rsp)
responseXML = responseXML.GetChildElements()
'responseArray = responseXML.GetChildElements()

result = []

for each xmlItem in responseXML      
    item = {}
    item.TITLE = xmlItem.getAttributes().title
    item.ContentList = GetApiArray(xmlItem.getAttributes().feed)
    result.push(item)
end for
```

but when i pass the second url to fetch the contents it wont work

```
Function GetApiArray(url as String)
    newXfer = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
    newXfer.SetUrl(url)
    response = newXfe.GetToString()

    responseXML = ParseXML(response)
    responseXML = responseXML.GetChildElements()
    responseArray = responseXML.GetChildElements()
```

and this is the log

```
> Suspending threads... Thread selected:  0*   pkg:/source/main.brs(112)
> responseXML = responseXML.GetChildElements()
> 
> Current Function: 106:  Function GetApiArray(url as String) 107:     
> newXfer = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer") 108:      newXfer.SetUrl(url)
> 109:      response = newXfer.GetToString() 110:   111:     
> responseXML = ParseXML(response) 112:*     responseXML =
> responseXML.GetChildElements() 113:      responseArray =
> responseXML.GetChildElements() 114:   115:      result = [] 116:  
> 'Dot' Operator attempted with invalid BrightScript Component or
> interface reference. (runtime error &hec) in pkg:/source/main.brs(112)
> 112:     responseXML = responseXML.GetChildElements() Backtrace:
> #2  Function getapiarray(url As String) As Dynamic    file/line: pkg:/source/main.brs(112)
> #1  Function makerequest() As Dynamic    file/line: pkg:/source/main.brs(54)
> #0  Function runuserinterface() As Void    file/line: pkg:/source/main.brs(15) Local Variables: url              roString
> (2.1 was String) refcnt=2 val:"https://contentsFeed.xml" global       
> Interface:ifGlobal m                roAssociativeArray refcnt=4
> count:1 newxfer          roUrlTransfer refcnt=1 response        
> roString (2.1 was String) refcnt=1 val:"" responsexml      Invalid
> responsearray    <uninitialized> result       <uninitialized> xmlitem 
> <uninitialized> itemaa           <uninitialized> item            
> <uninitialized> Threads: ID    Location                               
> Source Code  0*   pkg:/source/main.brs(112)               responseXML
> = responseXML.GetChildElements()   *selected
> 
> Brightscript Debugger>
```

so what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on line 109 ;)

You are using `newXfe` instead of `newXfer`.

See the error:

> 'Dot' Operator attempted with invalid BrightScript Component or
>   interface reference. (runtime error &hec) in pkg:/source/main.brs(109)

That's because `newXfe` is uninitialized (obviously).

Comment: Thank you Alejandro for your respond, actually i mid this typo after changing the code more than 100 times and working on it until 4 am lol, it wasn't the main error and i didn't notice the log when i copy it sorry for that it was so late check the edit this is the right log

Comment: That new crash seems to be due to the response not being an XML. Based on the logs that you pasted, the url says that it's "https://contentsfeed.xml/", did you edit that to share here on stackoverflow or that's actually the url you were trying to reach, because is clearly invalid. Also please fix the formatting on those logs, paste them as code block, not a quote, and add everything the debugger shows, like local variables and so on.

Comment: Yes i had to change the real xml url when i post the info, I did checked the real urls by pass them directly to the call and they worked fine, the problem is when i pass them as a variable and in Roku documentation they use the same code to achieve that .

Comment: I tried to move the xml files to another server and everything work fine i think it was a cross-origin-request error from one of the content xml hosting, we was using more than one server for that, Thank You for your help